# How to render <select> tag without rendering the carat and label name

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to render a button which on click renders the  dropdown but I do not want to render the carat and the selected label which is rendered by default. is it possible to override this functionality and only show the button but have the select functionality underneath it?

So when the user clicks on the button I render the  dropdown as shown below. I know creating a custom dropdown is possible but trying to use default for better browser support.

Thanks

```
  </button>
      {isOpen ?
        <select>
        <option>Apples</option>
        <option>Oranges</option>
        <option>Banannas</option>
      </select>
        : null}
    </div>
```

I have the logic to open and close it. If you see this [w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select](https://w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) you see that the carat and volvo is displayed, I want to replace it with the button I made but still have the same underlying functionality. So basically hide the carat and the label while showing it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS propery exactly to hide the default browser element: `appearance: none`. However, it is not supported in all browsers ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)) and you need to add vendor prefixes (`-webkit-` and `-moz-`).

Here is an example:

```css
.select-2 {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 0;
  padding: 4px 7px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-1">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>

<select class="select-2">
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer.  What I am trying to do is that when the user opens the page there would be a button with a image when the user clicks the button the dropdown  would be rendered which would have the text option for example [apple,banana,orange] when user clicks orange the dropdown is closed an the orange image in only shown on the main page. I have the logic to handle all of that but trying to come up with a logic to toggle between the image and text on close/open

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly when you press the button you change the value of isOpen from false to true, then try this syntax:

```
{isOpen && (
    <select>
    <option>Apples</option>
    <option>Oranges</option>
    <option>Banannas</option>
  </select>
    )}
```

Comment: Yes I have the logic to open and close it. If you see this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select 
you see that the carat and volvo is displayed, I want to replace it with the button I made but still have the same underlying functionality. So basically hide the carat and the label while showing it to the user.

Comment: So what you mean is you, is that you want to hide the select element, and when the user clicks on the button, you want to show it, right?

Comment: Sadly no! The answer by hrep3 is close to what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

FYI for people who might end up here I managed to achieve this functionality by removing the button and sending styles to the select component itself . I hid the text for the image by setting opacity to 0 and provided a background image such that -

In the case of options being [Orange, Apple, Banana]
 - The user first time sees the image of Orange
 - When the user clicks the select with the orange user sees the above options in text -> User clicks apple
 - Dropdown is closed and the select now has the apple image to reflect the selection.